# WebStorm open folder in terminal and automatically rename session to folder name

Tags: webstorm

When I open a folder in terminal using `right click` - `Open in Terminal` the new Terminal session runs with a default given Tab name `Local`.

I have more than one apps in my monorepo and when I open them all in Terminals, the bottom Terminal window section looks like this:

`Local` | `Local (1)` | `Local (2)` | `Local (3)` | `Local (4)`

It is uncomfortable to first rename all these sessions to the names of the application folders. I found no option in the `preferences` - `Terminal` settings.

Is there any chance to configure WebStorm to automatically rename the tabs to the folder names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no such option, please vote for [IDEA-146714](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-146714) to be notified on any progress with it